# Take certain values from HashMap and create a list of them

Tags: java

The user can enter anything in to a search field that I've created. I want to select the values from my existing HashMap that have the same name as what the user entered and put them in a list.

I've tried something like this but it obviously takes ALL the values of the pre existing HashMap:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(map.values());
```

My goal is to create a map with the String the user entered as a key and the list with the objects that have the same name as value.

EDIT:

KEY and VALUE: The key is a point class with X and Y coordinates and the values are Place classes, basically a location with a name. Map Point, Place allPlaces = ..

I want to find objects that have the same name as the user typed in to the search field.

Right now I'm iterating through my entire HashMap:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<Position, Place>> iterator = 
allPlaces.entrySet().iterator();

            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                Place place = (Place)iterator.next().getValue();
                place.setUnMarked();
                if (place.getName().equals(searchField.getText()) && 
           (place.isVisible()==false || place.isVisible())){
                    place.setMarked();
                    place.setVisible(true);
                    markedPlaces.add(place);
                }
            }
```

, but this is really an inefficient way to find only a couple of Places with that certain name.

Comment: can you provide example?

Comment: The structure you have described is a Multimap. A Hashmap is 1 to 1.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your existing HashMap to get a better understanding of your values? At least give one key-value pair.

Comment: The key is a point class with X and Y coordinates and the values are Place classes, basically a location with a name.
Map<Point, Place> allPlaces = ..

Comment: Read the edit, I tried to give an example(part of my code).

Answer (score 0):

> The user can enter anything in to a search field that I've created. I
>   want to select the values from my existing **HashMap** that have the same
>   name as what the user entered and put them in a list.

`HashMap` can have only 1 value for 1 unique key.
Unless it will be a `HashMap<String,Collection<?>>` every key will have only single value so there is nothing to make collection of. If it is, then you have collection out of the box.

If you are talking about user input beeing a multiple key choice, simply iterate over keys, and add  to array, or even better, use Java8 stream API

```
HashMap<String,String> values= my hashmap
List<String> input = userinput keywords

List<String> result=input.stream().map(values::get).collect(Collections.toList());
```

Comment: I want to efficiently iterate through a list with selected values instead of going through my big HashMap to search for only a few items if you know what I mean.

Comment: Like is there any way to only put the values that meet a certain criteria in a list?

Comment: You dont understand the whole idea of hashmap - it is made to fast lookup. You dont iterate over hashmap, you only lookup value.

Comment: And you need to decide, you are either talking about map, or list - those are 2 different things. 
The code i have shown you is not dependant on size of map but on size of user input. Map can be as large as you want, and it will still be fast to get value from it by key.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do any more efficient than iterating over values and comparing your field to some string as HashMap lookup works by key not value.

One thing you could do is to use [BidiMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html) if you can ensure 1:1 mapping.